# Перебор XmlNodeList и xpath в C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, .net-core

При выполнении кода:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<Root><Node>Node1</Node><Node>Node2</Node><Node>Node3</Node></Root>");
foreach (XmlNode node in document.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='Node']"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
    Console.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='Node']").InnerText);
}
```

Получается результат:

```
<Node>Node1</Node>
Node1
<Node>Node2</Node>
Node1
<Node>Node3</Node>
Node1
```

Почему метод `SelectSingleNode` с выражением `xpath` всегда возвращает `Node1`? 
Почему поиск осуществляется не в рамках узла у которого данный метод был вызван, а по всему документу?
Мне казалось есть узел, есть его содержимое, есть метод, вызываемый у этого узла, есть некая работа метода, связанная с этим узлом и вот результат, связанный с этим узлом.
Что я не понимаю и как это исправить, что бы результат зависел от текущего узла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы ведь уже нашли нужные вам ноды, и перебираете их в цикле. Просто уберите повторный поиск:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml("<Root><Node>Node1</Node><Node>Node2</Node><Node>Node3</Node></Root>");
foreach (XmlNode node in document.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='Node']"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Если нужно искать в рамках текущей ноды, а не в рамках всего документа - не начинайте xpath с `//`:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(
@"<Root>
<Node><a>Node1</a></Node>
<Node><a>Node2</a></Node>
<Node><a>Node3</a></Node>
</Root>");

foreach (XmlNode node in document.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='Node']"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
    Console.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("a").InnerText);
}
```

---

```
<Node><a>Node1</a></Node>
Node1
<Node><a>Node2</a></Node>
Node2
<Node><a>Node3</a></Node>
Node3
```